# C# How Do I parse variable?

Tags: c#

```
//Prompts user for their age
int age;
ApplicationUtilitiesinternal.DisplayDivider("Get Age");
Console.WriteLine("What is your age? ");

while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age)) //Makes sure the user inputs a number for their age
    Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a valid age - try again.");

age = InputUtilities.GetInput("Age");
```

I know I need to parse the variable, age, but I'm not sure how to do it. I've tried several methods and searched the web for answers. Just when I think I had it...another error would pop up. I know this should be simple.

Edit:

Okay, I'm going to add some context here. Here's what I have to call from:

```
class InputUtilities
{
    internal static string GetInput(string inputType)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your " + inputType);
        string strInput = Console.ReadLine();
        return strInput;
    }
}
```

I hope this makes more sense now.

Comment: Don't you already parsing it with `int.TryParse`?

Comment: Yes, as soon as the while-loop exits, you have the age in your `age` variable. So no need to use `InputUtilities` here.

Comment: It's the way the program has to be done.

Comment: @BlueMoonNinja: Make sure age > 0.

Comment: Oh I didn't even think of that but that's not my worry right now.

Comment: You haven't really stated what the problem is. You said you can't call `Console.ReadLine()`, but you are. You haven't shown anybody what `GetInput` does. There's a lot of context missing here.

Comment: How is a user supposed to enter his age?

Comment: You are parsing a string from the console into the `age` variable, and then immediately overwriting it. Either you don't want to call `Console.ReadLine` or you don't need `GetInput`.

Comment: You are also calling InputUtilties.GetInput() which reutrns a string but you are trying to assign it to an int value (age) - this won't even compile!

Comment: Per your edit, just do this: `while (!int.TryParse(InputUtilities.GetInput("Age"), out age))`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your actual question: "I know I need to parse the variable, age, but I'm not sure how to do it.", as already stated by others, you ARE doing it.

I've ignored your `ApplicationUtilitiesinternal` and `InputUtilities` classes as they don't appear to be relevant to your requirement, along with the fact that `InputUtilities.GetInput()` returns a string and you are trying to assign it to an `int` (`age`).

I suggest this code should make things clearer:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age (1-120):");
int nAge;
while(true)
{
    string sAge = Console.ReadLine();
    if(!int.TryParse(sAge, out nAge))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a valid age - try again.");
        continue;
    }
    if(nAge <= 0 || nAge > 120)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter an age between 1 and 120");
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
// At this point, nAge will be a value between 1 and 120
```